# C++: How to avoid unwanted comparison because implicit convert to bool

Tags: c++

I have a class like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


class A {
    public:
        operator bool() const { return m_value != 0; }
        int m_value {0};
};


int main() {
        A a = A();
        a.m_value = 1;
        A b = A();
        b.m_value = 2;
        if (a == b) {
                printf("Wrong!\n");
        }
}
```

I forget to override the comparison operator for `A`. But because the operator bool, this code compiles without even a warning, result in an unwanted comparison.

Is there a way I can detect behavior like this automatically? like a compile flag.

Comment: Would `explicit operator bool()` be appropriate for your design?

Comment: @BenVoigt In reality if I remember to add explicit to operator bool, I possibly will remember overriding the comparison operator too. I want a linter to catch my mistake when I forget to add explicitly and override.

Comment: You can't expect a compiler or linter to catch everything you intended to do but forgot.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're asking if there's a compiler flag so that the language makes explicit the default? No, there isn't.

Comment: Well, it's much easier to write a static analysis rule to catch `explicit` missing from `operator bool()` than to detect "unwanted comparison".

Comment: Thank you all. Looks like writing a static analysis rule to force explicit operator bool() is the closing thing I can do now. Would be great if there is a compile flag in the future.

Comment: This does't address the question, but "override" is not the correct term here. A derived class can override a virtual function defined in a  base class. That' obviously not the case here. The goal is to **overload** the comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the [explicit specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) is for:

```
   explicit operator bool() const { return m_value != 0; }
// ^^^^^^^^
```

Now implicit conversions from `A` to `bool` will be a hard compiler error.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G6xEE4).

Comment: In reality if I remember to add explicit to operator bool, I possibly will remember overriding the comparison operator too. I want a linter to catch my mistake when I forget to add explicitly and override.